# How to convert image into base64 encoding format

Tags: javascript, php, encoding

I have a variable containing image which is returned from `imagecopyresampled` function, I want to convert this variable into base64 encoded format to return to my JavaScript file.
Error is that `base64_encode` and `exif_imagetype` funcions do not take image as input.
Here is my code:

```
<?php

$img_name     = $_POST['name'];
$data         = file_get_contents($img_name);
$crop_start_x = $_POST['crop_start_x'];
$crop_start_y = $_POST['crop_start_y'];
$crop_width   = $_POST['crop_width'];
$crop_height  = $_POST['crop_height'];

$dst_x = 0;
$dst_y = 0;
$src_x = $crop_start_x;
$src_y = $crop_start_y;
$dst_w = $crop_width;
$dst_h = $crop_height;
$src_w = $src_x + $dst_w;
$src_h = $src_y + $dst_h;

$dst_image = imagecreatetruecolor($dst_w, $dst_h);
$src_image = imagecreatefromstring($data);

imagecopyresampled($dst_image, $src_image, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $dst_w, $dst_h, $src_w, $src_h);

$type         = exif_imagetype($dst_image);
$base64_image = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($dst_image);

echo $base64_image;

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work

```
$image = 'folder/your_image.png';
$type = pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$imgdata = file_get_contents($image);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($imgdata);
```

for imagecopyresampled

```
imagecopyresampled($dst_image, $src_image, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $dst_w, $dst_h, $src_w, $src_h);
ob_start();
imagejpeg($dst_image, null);
$img = ob_get_clean();
$base64 = base64_encode($img)
```

Comment: see this code needs $image on a path thats why pathinfo and base64_encode works, but in my case i have dst_image as return from imagecopyresampled function, there is type difference.

Comment: edited the above code, now you can try with this@user3661745

Comment: Ok Thankyou this worked. i want to return this string to JavaScript and decode it there to display. can you please help me how to handle that?

Comment: document.getElementById("img_element_id).setAttribute('src', "data:image/jpg;base64," + base64img);

Comment: Thankyou so much!